# Add QWidget created in designer to a QToolbar

Tags: c++, qt

I have added a new designer form class to my project that is a widget. Using designer i have added some buttons and labels etc to the widget (which i want to use as my toolbar).

The .cpp and .h files for the widget are untouched and basically just as they are when a new widget is created in qt.

i have a different form that i have added a QToolbar to and now i want to add my widegt to that tool bar

i added this code to my constructor of the form i want the toolbar on, m_horizontalToolBar was declared in the header like this `std::shared_ptr<HorizontalToolbar> m_horizontalToolbar;`

```
QToolBar *tool = new QToolBar;
tool->addWidget(m_horizontalMapToolbar.get());
this->addToolBar(tool);
```

this compiles and runs but nothing displays in the toolbar

I have had a look at this question

The person seems to have got it working but it doesnt really say how at all

seeing as how tool bar has an "addWidget" function i assume this is possible, any light on this would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure your Widget is properly initialized ? Does `m_horizontalMapToolbar.get()` may return a NULL-Pointer? Have you tried to add a QComboBox for example, pretty sure its not the `addWidget()` is the problem, but rather that what you want to add.

Comment: yea thanks its sorted now your right i wasnt initializing it, see answer and comment, cheers anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your `HorizontalToolbar` class.

```
m_horizontalMapToolbar = std::make_shared<HorizontalToolbar>();
```